# Android/Java - Why am I getting a "Cannot find symbol method startForground"?

Tags: java, android, methods, service

I am getting a:

```
Error:(393, 9) cannot find symbol method startForeground(int,android.app.Notification)
```

I am trying to run my GPS/Commuting app in the Foreground so that it is always treated as a foreground app. Here is my code snippet where I attempt to start the foreground service:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    Intent intentForeground = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
    intentForeground.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentForeground,0);
    pendingIntent.cancel();
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentForeground,0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText("Yup1")
            .setTicker("Yup2")
            .setAutoCancel(false);

    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
    startForeground(123, notification);
}
```

My build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:+'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client:1.0.16+'
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `startForeground()`?

Comment: First off, shouldn't you be handing startForeground the notification variable? Not a new Notification()? Second, have you tried using startForegroundCompat()

Comment: @Takendarkk startForeground() is an API so I dont have code for it

Comment: @Spidy Yes, you are correct. I made the change to the code above that you suggested. Still same problem though. And no, I havent tried startForegroundCompat but cant find an example anywhere to figure out how to use it.